# Flutter : Multipart File request not working

Tags: api, flutter, http, multipart

I want to upload image by multipart File request. With using this code  When I pass two image files then it's working fine. But when I want to pass one image file and another is null then it's not working.
where is the problem? How can I solve this ?

Here is my code -

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> updateprofile(
      UpdateProfileInfo updateProfileInfo,
      File imageFile,
      File signatureFile) async {

    String url = "$baseAPIUrl/update-profile-info";
    String _token = await SavedData().loadToken();
    String authorization = "Bearer $_token";

    final headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      "Authorization": authorization
    };

    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(url));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    request.fields.addAll(updateProfileInfo.toJson());

    request.files
        .add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageFile.path));
    request.files.add(
        await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('signature', signatureFile.path));

    print(" Update Profile Json ${updateProfileInfo.toJson()}");
    print("Request Fields ${request.fields}");
    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    String respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    dynamic respJson;

    try {
      respJson = jsonDecode(respStr);
    } on FormatException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }

    print('API ${response.statusCode}\n  $respJson');

    bool isSuccess = response.statusCode == 200;
    var data = json.decode(respStr);

    return {
      'isSuccess': isSuccess,
      "message": isSuccess ? data["success"]["message"] : null,
      "name": isSuccess ? data["success"]["name"] : null,
      "classgroup": isSuccess ? data["success"]["classgroup"] : null,
      "image": isSuccess ? data["success"]["image"] : null,
      "error": isSuccess ? null : data['error']['message'],
    };
  }
```

Here is postman Screenshot

**1.**

[image]

**2. POSTMAN Generated code for Dart - http**

[image]

Comment: how do you know that *" ... it's not working."*?

Comment: means you want to pass multiple images for single request in one parameter right ?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Sorry, not one parameter. I passed two parameters File imageFile and File signatureFile

Comment: @pskink By seeing my output, It's seems like that, It's not hit to my API

Comment: @AbirAhsan https://gist.github.com/aTeamSolace/ece5585f4142b0948ce7cfb1da6c5748

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Sorry, I edited my comment. please check

Comment: @pskink don't have any response, waited about 1 minute but no response. But when I passed one parameter, it's response me quickly

Comment: tried to use https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/network ?

Comment: @pskink I found the exact  issue, When I use this code for two Image File, but send one Image, and another is null then it  don't reponse

Comment: @AbirAhsan so it fixed?

Comment: @JohnJoe exact problem found but not fixed

Comment: @AbirAhsan have you checked why it is null ? Or try send a null image using postman, did the server return anything?

Comment: @JohnJoe When I send a null image by postman It's send to my api a dummy path that's why it's working.

postman code- request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('signature', '/path/to/file'));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when one of your file is null, you should avoid adding it to the request body.

```
if(imageFile != null){
    request.files
        .add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageFile.path));
}
if(signatureFile != null){
request.files.add(
        await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('signature', signatureFile.path));
}
```

its because `signatureFile.path` is going to cause an error here

Comment: Not working . Getting an error "Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = 'File: '/data/user/0/com.tcs.tryon_v5/cache/image_picker3432035215283692220.jpg'' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)"

Answer (score 1):

using dio package should work

```
   Future<bool> updateImage(var pickedFile) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();` <br/>
    var token = sharedPreferences.getString("token");
    Dio dio = Dio(); 
    final File file = File(pickedFile.path);
   String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
   dio.options.headers["authorization"] = token;
   FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
     "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path),
     });
    try {
     var response = await dio.post(API.kBASE_URL, data: formData);
           if (response.statusCode == 200) {
           return true;
           } else {
                   return false;
                 }
          } catch (r) {
                        return false;
                       }
     }
```